# Highstock - custom tickPositioner and tickInterval

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a Highstock chart here

http://jsfiddle.net/AVhaL/28/

What I want to do is to display the "Month, Year" on the x-axis, and show only distinct "Month, Year" labels.

The obvious way is to set the skip interval

```
tickInterval: 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000,
```

But as you can see in the chart, "Mar 11" appears twice. I tried with "31", and even "32", but "Mar 11" doesn't go away.

Answer (score 0):

Try with 35, the problem is solved.

```
xAxis: {
        tickInterval: 35 * 24 * 3600 * 1000,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update your tickPositioner and return ticks with interval.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/AVhaL/29/

```
 tickPositioner: function () {
            var positions = [],
                tick = Math.floor(this.dataMin),
                increment = 31 * 24 * 3600 * 1000;

            for (tick; tick - increment <= this.dataMax; tick += increment) {
                positions.push(tick);
            }
            return positions;
        }
```